# Converting (alpha) hulls to spatial polygon

Tags: r, polygon, r-sf, convex-hull

In R, I wish to convert the alpha shape polygon surrounding a bunch of points into one single spatial polygon object.

```
library(sf)
library(alphahull)
```

To start out, I create the point random points distribution

```
dat <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5, 3,3,5,6,9), ncol = 2)
```

I find the alpha shape covering the points (i.e. a polygon encompassing all points). I am particularly interested in this function as it has the feature to find a more or less tight polygon shape according to the given alpha

```
dat.ashape<- ashape(dat, alpha= 7)
```

I take the coordinates of the extreme

```
coords<- dat.ashape$x[dat.ashape$alpha.extreme,]
```

I make the last point same as the first (to have a closed shape)

```
coords<- rbind(coords, coords[1,])
```

To make things to work I need to order the point in sequence

```
coords<- cbind(coords, NA) 
coords[,3]<- c(1, 5, 3, 2, 4, 6) 
coords<- coords[order(coords[,3]),]
```

I create the simple spatial point feature from the coordinate matrix

```
dat.sf <- st_multipoint(coords, dim = "XYZ")
```

... and create the polygon

```
tst<- dat.sf %>% # 
  st_cast('POLYGON')
```

Finally, comparing the point and shape distribution and the polygon, I was able to build the polygon correctly, but this is rather easy with six points! (Because I made myself manually the right order)

```
plot(dat.ashape) 
plot(tst, add=T, col=adjustcolor('red', alpha.f=.3), border=2)
```

In a more sophisticated example with say 100 points, I get stuck in the part where I should get the sequence of points right, before st_cast into polygon.

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- matrix(stats::rnorm(100), ncol = 2)
dat.ashape<- ashape(dat, alpha=7)
coords<- dat.ashape$x[dat.ashape$alpha.extreme,] 
coords<- rbind(coords, coords[1,]) 

dat.sf <- st_multipoint(coords, dim = "XY")

tst <- dat.sf %>%
  st_cast('POLYGON')

plot(dat.ashape)
plot(tst, add=T, col=adjustcolor('red', alpha.f=.3), col.line='red', border=2)
```

.... and I obviously do not get trick done.

I am grateful for any help!

Comment: The second polygon looks kind of good to me? If this is not what you expect, please be more specific in what your goal is. Does the polygon need to touch all points?

Comment: Thanks @Julian_Hn, I made some edit in the hope to make my goal clearer. Yes the polygon needs to touch all the external points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I was not happy with the `concaveman`. I really wanted the [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) as basis of my hull computation as I like `alphahull` a lot. Also, after reading [this](https://babichmorrowc.github.io/post/2019-03-18-alpha-hull/) I wanted to find a (or my) viable way for converting the hull retrieved from `alphahull` package to a spatial polygon, which I could further use for my broader spatial analysis. Therefore I wrote the following function to do the job:

```
hull2poly <- function(my.ashape){
  require(sf)
  if(class(my.ashape) != "ashape") {stop('error, your input must be 
     ashape class')} else
     my.edge<- data.frame(my.ashape$edges)[,c( 'x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2')]
     x<- my.edge[,1:2]
     y<- my.edge[,3:4]
     my.edge2<- matrix(t(cbind(x,y)), byrow=T,ncol=2)
     my.edge2<- as.data.frame(my.edge2)
     names(my.edge2)<- c('x','y')
     my.edge2$id <- unlist(lapply((1: (nrow(my.edge2)/2)), 
                                  FUN=function(x){c(rep(x,2))}))

     start.edge<- 1
     new.id<- start.edge
     new.edges<- my.edge2[which(my.edge2$id== start.edge ),]

     while(length(new.id)<= length(unique(my.edge2$id))-1){
           internal.id<- new.id[length(new.id)]
           edge <- my.edge2[which(my.edge2$id== internal.id ),]
           where.to.search <- my.edge2[which(my.edge2$id %in% new.id ==F ),]
  
     index1<- apply(where.to.search[,1:2], 1, function(x){x == edge[1,1:2]})
     index1<- as.numeric(names(which(apply(index1,2, sum)>0)))[1]
     index2<- apply(where.to.search[,1:2], 1, function(x){x == edge[2,1:2]})
     index2<- as.numeric(names(which(apply(index2,2, sum)>0)))[1]
     main.index<- c(index1, index2)
  
     ifelse(all(!is.na(main.index)), 
         # yes
         {flag<- c(T,T)
         main.index<- main.index[2]
         point.coord<- my.edge2[main.index,] 
         segment<- my.edge2[my.edge2$id==my.edge2[main.index,'id'],]
         new.id<- c( new.id, my.edge2[main.index,]$id) },
         
         # no
         ifelse(which(!is.na(main.index))==1, 
                # yes
                {flag<- c(T,F)
                main.index<- main.index[flag]
                point.coord<- my.edge2[main.index,] 
                segment<- 
     my.edge2[my.edge2$id==my.edge2[main.index,'id'],]
                new.id<- c( new.id, my.edge2[main.index,]$id)},
                # no
                {flag<- c(F,T)
                main.index<- main.index[flag]
                point.coord<- my.edge2[main.index,] 
                segment<- my.edge2[my.edge2$id==my.edge2[main.index,'id'],]
                new.id<- c( new.id, my.edge2[main.index,]$id)}  ) )
  
        index3<- t(apply(segment, 1, function(x){x ==point.coord}))
  
        new.edges<- rbind(new.edges, rbind(point.coord, segment[which(apply(index3,1, sum)<3),]))
}
tst <- st_multipoint(as.matrix(new.edges), dim = "XYZ")
poly<- tst %>% # 
  st_cast('POLYGON')
return(poly)}
```

So, if you wish to give a try with a cloud of 1000 points:

```
library(alphahull)
set.seed(1)
dat <- matrix(stats::rnorm(1000), ncol = 2)
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)
dat.ashape<- ashape(dat, alpha= 2) 

tmp<- hull2poly(dat.ashape)

plot(tmp)
```

I hope, it comes useful for someone.

Comment: In your function, defining the variables x and y is not necessary, since `identical(cbind(x,y), my.edge)` is `TRUE`. But in the `while` loop I fail to follow all of your steps. Can you point out to me which steps to do so that I only get a data.frame with the coordinates of the sorted data? (I want to plot only them with `lines()`).

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer just above (thanks!). For me this worked using sf only:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(alphahull)

# get your ashape object
aoi <- ashape(pts, alpha = 2000)

# converted to sf polygons
a <- data.frame(aoi$edges)[,c( 'x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2')]
l <- st_linestring(matrix(as.numeric(a[1,]), ncol=2, byrow = T))
for(i in 2:nrow(a)){
  l <- c(l, st_linestring(matrix(as.numeric(a[i,]), ncol=2, byrow = T)))
}
alphapoly <- st_sf(geom = st_sfc(l), crs = 2056) %>% st_polygonize() %>% st_collection_extract()
```

Answer (score 1):

Searching for further alternatives to packages `alphahull`, `rgeos`, `sf` for computing the hull surrounding a bunch of points, I finally found `concaveman` thanks to [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/302110), which does the trick, being compatible with sf objects.

```
library(concaveman)
library(sf)

set.seed(1)
dat <- matrix(stats::rnorm(100), ncol = 2)
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)
names(dat)<- c('x', 'y')
dat.sf<-st_as_sf(dat, coords=c("x","y"))

polygon <- concaveman(dat.sf)
plot(dat.sf, pch=16)
plot(polygon, add=T, col=adjustcolor('red', alpha.f=.3), col.line='red', border=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer wouldn't work for my dataset so I found another way.
First I used the coordinate pairs to create the line segments of the alpha shape.  Then I just bound those line segments together and converted that to a polygon.

```
library(sp)
library(sf)
library(alphahull)

dat.ashape<- ashape(dat, alpha=7)

a<- data.frame(dat.ashape$edges)[,c( 'x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2')]

# create first line segment to initialize the object
i=1
line_obj <- sp::Line(cbind(  c(a$x1[i], a$x2[i]),c(a$y1[i], a$y2[i])  ))
lines_obj <- sp::Lines(list(line_obj),ID=i)
myLines <- sp::SpatialLines(list(lines_obj))

for (i in 2:nrow(a)){
  line_obj <- sp::Line(cbind(  c(a$x1[i], a$x2[i]),c(a$y1[i], a$y2[i])  ))
  lines_obj <- sp::Lines(list(line_obj),ID=i)
  myLines <- rbind(myLines, sp::SpatialLines(list(lines_obj))) #bind the line to the rest
}

sfL<-as(myLines, "sf") #convert lines to sf
alphapoly = st_collection_extract(st_polygonize(st_union(sfL))) # union the lines and convert to polygon
apol<-as_Spatial(alphapoly) #if you want to convert back to sp

library(leaflet)  #plot the line segments and polygon in Leaflet
 leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addPolygons(data=apol) %>% addPolylines(data=myLines, color="yellow")
```